# Sample of items, find probability that at least one is defective

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Items are packaged in boxes of 100 each. A sampling inspection plan calls for rejecting a box if a sample of 5 drawn from that box contain 1 or more defectives. What is the probability that a box containing exactly 4 defectives is rejected?

I determined that the probability of a defective = $4/100 = .04$, call this $q$, and the probability of not defective = $.96 = p$.

In a sample of 5, I decided the probability of at least one defective is:
$$\sum_1^5 \binom{5}{n}p^nq^{5-n} = 1 - .96^5 = .184627$$

The answer provided in the book is $.19$. If I were to round to the nearest hundredth, I'd have $.18$. Is this just a rounding issue or is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: I would say you count correctly.

Comment: Thanks I should hope so! But is the probability correct?

Comment: Yes, probability is right.

Comment: Perhaps the author calculated it to three places .185 then rounded to .19.